# How to wrote a test for method in controller with DI?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have invocable controller for rendering some pdf. In route I only need to pass some string as parameter and my method look like this:

```
public function __invoke(
        Request $request,
        IncidentPdfGenerationService $incidentPdfGenerationService,
        string $report
    ) {
        $pdf = $incidentPdfGenerationService->getRawPdf($request, $report);
        $name = $report . '.pdf';

        return $pdf->stream($name);
    }
```

and this is what I have:

```
/** @test */
    public function generate_incidents_pdf()
    {
        $this->user->syncRoles(['system admin', 'field manager', 'field officer', 'reports admin']);

        $this->actingAs($this->user);

        $this->mock(IncidentPdfGenerationService::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getRawPdf')->once();

            $mock->getRawPdf(request(), 'pdf-report');

            $url = route('incidents.generate-pdf', ['pdf-report']);

            $response = Http::get($url);

            $response->ok();
        });
    }
```

`IncidentPdfGenerationService` is a interface and I bind that in service provider. How to wrote a test to check this route with only assertStatus(200)?

Comment: `$response = $this->get('route'); $response->assertStatus(200);` Does this not work for you? Pass the parameters required, of course.

Comment: No because I need this service and I get error that I need to pass that service for this method

Comment: User mockery then

Comment: yes but I don't know how to trigger this route with mockery because I am testing controller only

Comment: Please share what you've got so far

Comment: yes, I updated my question with test that I have

Answer (score 1):

You should try not to have to create any dependancies when testing a service or alike. I would suggest using [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html) to do this as you can create a dummy version of the `IncidentPdfGenerationService` dependancy.

Comment: yes but I don't know how to trigger this route with mockery because I am testing controller only